# Expressing Respect

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests, idioms

I am looking for a short expression to show my respect to someone who is living in a difficult situation. I live in Germany and they would say "Hut ab" or "Hats off", but in English this is a way of congratulating someone. Any suggestions?

Comment: Sometimes people encourage each other saying, _**Hang in there!**_ It might help if you described in which situation you would use _**Hut ab**_. Your question might be closed for lack of clarity.

Comment: "Robert Schumann’s celebrated assessment of Frédéric Chopin—“Hut ab, ihr Herren, ein Genie!” (Hats off, gentlemen, a genius!)—appeared in his 1831 review of Chopin’s variations on *Là ci darem la mano*, op. 2." [ref](https://bibliolore.org/2017/03/09/chopin-on-schumann/)

Comment: Merriam-Webster says ["hats off to"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hats%20off%20to) is used to give "praise or credit" which seems close to your desired meaning. There is a range of things you could say to someone in a difficult situation, from "well done for keeping going" to "how awful, I sympathise and am here to help". So it's not entirely clear what you want.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of thing depends on what that situation is. Whether its that a loved one died or they have become broke etc. Saying "I'm here if you need me" is always great, but if they know that you are from Germany then you should be able to say "hats off" and it will mean the same.

Comment: "I'm thinking of you" (or "You are in my thoughts) at this difficult time" is another possibility.